# org.hibernate.QueryException: Expected positional parameter count: 1, actual parameters: [] [CALL usp_LoginDetails(?, :p_login)]

Tags: spring, hibernate, oracle11g

I am trying my best but i am not able to resolve this error please help me.

DaoImplimentation file:

```
  @Override
            public LoginProcedure getLoginProcedureByNamedQuery(String p_login) {


            try {

         Query lquery = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession().getNamedQuery("dd");

                      lquery.setParameter("p_login", p_login);
        List ll= lquery.list();

             System.out.println("value of ll"+ll);
        }

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
            }
```

Hbm file :

```
     <![CDATA[CALL usp_LoginDetails(?, :p_login)]]>   

    </sql-query>
```

Error coming :

2015-09-18 18:06:05,769 ERROR [stderr] (default task-31) org.hibernate.QueryException: Expected positional parameter count: 1, actual parameters: [] [CALL usp_LoginDetails(?, :p_login)]

Answer (score 0):

On your hbml file can you try the following syntax:

```
<sql-query callable="true"
   name="dd">{call usp_LoginDetails(:p_login)}
  <query-param name="p_login" type="string"/>  
 </sql-query>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply ,After changing ,getting following error:                           Hibernate: {call usp_LoginDetails(?)}

2015-09-19 12:40:25,751 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-15) SQL Error: 17003, SQLState: null
2015-09-19 12:40:25,751 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-15) Invalid column index
2015-09-19 12:40:25,754 ERROR [stderr] (default task-15) org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query

Comment: Check your query on usp_LoginDetails, did you try execute it on toad for example?